# pandas groupby column name part?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to group a dataframe by column name parts and then plot the pairs with one command?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5),columns=['2678_namex', '2354_namey', '2396_namex', '2398_namez', '2368_namey'] )
```

It should be the following groups:

```
[2678_namex , 2396_namex]  
[2354_namey , 2368_namey]
```

regards

Comment: What is your expected result looks like ?

Comment: Have to tried anything yourself? What error are you getting?

Comment: What is your expected? maybe you need minus this column then you need `dataframe['2678_namex-2354_namey'] = dataframe['2678_namex'] - dataframe['2354_namey']` or you expected group this columns `dataframe.groupby(['2678_namex','2354_namey']).mean()`?

Comment: I have not worked so long with the 'groupby' function, so I'm unsure if it's possible to apply this here. I have not found a suitable example in panda's help, so i ask here. 

I thought it might be possible to split the transposed dataframe with groupby into name paired datasets and then plot them in seperate figures. Maybe someone knows how to do that in a simple/fast oneliner.

Comment: @RudolfMorkovskyi, with your examples I do not reach the grouping as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
df.columns = list(map(lambda x:x.split('_')[1],df.columns))<br>
df.T.groupby(by=df.columns).sum()
```

Comment: if you want numeric part also in group name, then there will ambiguity for e.g which group name to be used for namez group which is grouping 2398_namez and 2789_namez

Comment: Thank you, that was already the solution. I misinterpreted the output of group.first. `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,6),columns=['2678_namex', '2354_namey', '2396_namex', '2398_namez', '2368_namey','2789_namez'])
df.columns = list(map(lambda x:x.split('_')[1],df.columns))
groups = df.T.groupby(by=df.columns)
for pairname, df in groups:
    df  = df.T
    df.plot()`